# Open-source Campfire alternative

Tags: chat

I've used [Campfire](http://campfirenow.com/) by 37Signals and thought it was pretty cool. A bit pricey for me though and I would only use it with friends so I want a free alternative. Found [TalkerApp](http://talkerapp.com/) and they offer a do a free version but it only offers public chat rooms.

Google Chat and Skype would've been great but they don't offer persistent chat rooms ( as far as I know)  and I would like the option to have the transcripts of conversations.

Comment: I was asking for an alternative. One app that can replace Campfire for me. Somebody please tell me why it deserves closing. I did not ask for a list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a list here:

http://alternativeto.net/software/campfire/

That might be useful.

[Echowaves](https://www.echowaves.com/) might fit the bill (open source)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice. Will check it out :D

Answer (score 2):

you *can* create a persistent channel on skype. You can also just bookmark any private channels to reuse them.